# C#. How fast insert Byte to Struct all time?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, struct, marshalling

Code For NET 2.0.

I write function  ByteArrayToObject for insert offset bytes in struct, but is it possible to quickly?
Is planned that there will be a lot of structures in which it is necessary to append the changed network information. If I can insert these bytes quickly to the right place, it will be organized in the protocol as one big structure. 
Thank you for any help.

In my case, I do not like that every time to replace the bytes that have to do all the copy of the object func ObjectToByteArray.

```
 /// <summary> Convert an object struct to a byte array </summary>
        private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {

            var size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
            // Both managed and unmanaged buffers required.
            var bytes = new byte[size];
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            // Copy object byte-to-byte to unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
            // Copy data from unmanaged memory to managed buffer.
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
            // Release unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return bytes;
        }

        /// <summary>  Need Faster ? </summary>
        public static T ByteArrayToObject<T>(ref T obj,  int StartOffset, params byte[] bytes) 
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
            int Length = (bytes.Length > size) ? size : bytes.Length;
            byte[] Allbytes = ObjectToByteArray(obj);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, Allbytes, StartOffset, Length - StartOffset);
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.Copy(Allbytes, 0, ptr, Length );
            obj = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return obj;
        }
```

Example use

```
    [Serializable]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
    struct Protocol
    {
        public byte f0;
        public byte f1;
        public short f2;
        public byte f3;
        public long f4;            
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20000)] 
        public int[] Array; // 20000

        }

       System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
       for (byte i = 1; i < 10; i++)
       {
           sw.Reset();
           sw.Start();
           ob = ByteArrayToObject<Protocol>(ref ob,1, i, 0x11, i, 0x22, i);
           sw.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine("Tick =" + sw.ElapsedTicks);
       }
```

Output

```
Tick =9940
Tick =686
Tick =593
Tick =474
Tick =562
Tick =5283
Tick =193
Tick =173
Tick =164
```

Comment: Good lord! What on earth are you trying to do? Edit: If it was just 1 struct type, going unsafe would be faster, but then you would have to do implement the same code for every type.

Comment: Just looking for the best way to work with the protocol.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. May work for you if you really want speed. Will be a bit more work, but same approach can be used for every struct type.

Comment: Updated the answer to match your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote a little

```
    public static unsafe void ByteArrayToEx(ref Ex  value, int offset, params byte[] bytes)
    {
        // you should add some safely nets here sizeof(Ex) should used for size of struct

        fixed (Ex* obj = &value)
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)obj;
            foreach (var b in bytes)
            {
                p[offset++] = b;
            }
        }
        // dont return value, it is expensive!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but to expand on the unsafe approach:

```
unsafe struct Ex
{
  public byte f0,f1,f2,f3,f4;
  public fixed int buffer[20000];
}

class Program
{
  public static unsafe void ByteArrayToEx(Ex* obj, int offset, params byte[] bytes)
  { 
    // you should add some safely nets here sizeof(Ex) should used for size of struct
    byte* p = (byte*)obj;
    foreach (var b in bytes)
    {
      p[offset++] = b;
    }
    // dont return value, it is expensive!
  }

  unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    Console.WriteLine(Stopwatch.Frequency);
    Ex e = new Ex { f0 = 0, f1 = 1, f2 = 2, f3 = 3, f4 = 4 };
    ByteArrayToEx(&e, 2, 5, 6, 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      sw.Restart();
      ByteArrayToEx(&e, 2, (byte) i, 6, 7);
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
    }
  }
}
```

This may or may not work for you. Also dont return the value. You are already mutating the pointer to it. Returning a copy of such a big struct adds 10 ticks to every call to it.

Also, you need to do at least 1 warmup when bench marking. That is why the first number is so poor.

Results on my PC:

```
3312929
4
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Somebody is going to have to start documenting their Stopwatch.Frequency or use Elapsed instead.  These numbers are completely meaningless to make any kind of comparison.  80 nanoseconds is *not* a lot of time.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yeah... I'll add that :) Edit: Using `Elapsed` is pointless due to the small test.

Comment: Thanks. But, How use template <T> ?

Comment: @askeet: You cannot when using `unsafe` as I have mentioned. The code is the same, just copy/paste and change the type.